# Тег META

Tags: xhtml, html

В данный момент задание ключевых слов, имя автора и описание страницы через атрибут "name" тега "meta" актуально или безжалостно игнорируется поисковиками? Как быть с динамичными страницами, где значения вышеуказанного атрибута должны меняться в зависимости от содержимого?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Поисковые машины учитывают содержание тэгов meta, хотя это содержание и не является определяющим: также имеет значение описание сайта в каталогах и собственно содержание индексируемой страницы.

На примере Google: [метатэги](http://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=ru&answer=79812) и [изменение заголовка и описания сайта в результатах поиска](http://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?answer=35264).

Comment: Спасибо, Мастер.